# RuntimeError: Expected a Tensor of type torch.FloatTensor but found a type torch.IntTensor for sequence element

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I wanna generate some random number with python and transform it to tensor with pytorch. Here is my code for generating the random number and transform it into tensor.

```
import numpy as np
import torch

P = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1, size=[20, 1])
k = np.random.randint(1, 20, size=[20, 1])
d_k = np.random.uniform(0, np.sqrt(80000), size=[20, 1])

P = torch.from_numpy(P).float()
k = torch.from_numpy(k).int()
d_k = torch.from_numpy(d_k).float()

torch.cat((P, k, d_k), dim=-1)
```

Afterward, I got some error which showed:

```
RuntimeError: Expected a Tensor of type torch.FloatTensor but found a type torch.IntTensor for sequence element 1 in sequence argument at position #1 'tensors'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `k` tensor is of dtype `torch.int32` while other tensors `P` and `d_k` are of dtype `torch.float32`. But the `cat` operation requires all the input tensors to be of same type. From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat)

> torch.cat(tensors, dim=0, out=None) → Tensor
>
> tensors (sequence of Tensors) – any python sequence of tensors of the
>   same type.

One of the solutions is to convert `k` to `float` dtype as follows:

```
k = torch.from_numpy(k).float()
```

Comment: It worked with float and double but cat operation needed everything as the same type. Thanks for the info